# How to improve "upsert" im mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Upserting work very slow , I want to improve it

I have about 3,000,000 documents in my mongo db.
I use this code to add documents

```
app.post('/addcontacts', (req, res) => {
    const jason = JSON.parse(req.body.body);


    async.eachOfLimit(jason, 30, function(value, index, callback){

        // upsert document, update all or insert if match not found
        myDb.collection('contacts').update(
            { n: value.n, p: value.p }, {n: value.n, p: value.p}, {upsert: true}, function(err){
                console.log("finshed: "+index);
                return callback(err);
        });

    }, function(err){
        // all is finished
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("finshed");
            return res.status(200).json({err: null});
        }
        db.close()
    })
});
```

the job become very slow, how I can improve it to became faster?

Answer (score 0):

mongodb is fast, try to improve your javascript's code. for eg. use

> Promise.all(map())

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
var promises = [obj1, obj2].map(function(obj){
  return db.query('obj1.id').then(function(results){
     obj1.rows = results
     return obj1
  })
})
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
})
```

i had insert  10lac  records with this in no time. so i hope this will work for you.